# How to interpret this fft graph

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing, fft

I want to apply Fourier transformation using `fft` function to my time series data to find "patterns" by extracting the dominant frequency components in the observed data, ie. the lowest 5 dominant frequencies to predict the y value (bacteria count) at the end of each time series.
I would like to preserve the smallest 5 coefficients as features, and eliminate the rest.

My code is as below:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/df.csv', sep=',') 
X = df.iloc[0:2,0:10000]

dft_X = np.fft.fft(X) 
print(dft_X) 
print(len(dft_X))
plt.plot(dft_X)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

# What is the graph about(freq/amplitude)? How much data did it use? 
for i in dft_X: 

    m = i[np.argpartition(i,5)[:5]]
    n = i[np.argpartition(i,range(5))[:5]]

print(m,'\n',n)
```

Here is the output: 
[image]

But I am not sure how to interpret this graph. To be precise,

1) Does the graph show the transformed values of the input data? I only used 2 rows of data(each row is a time series), thus data is `2x10000`, why are there so many lines in the graph?

2) To obtain frequency value, should I use `np.fft.fftfreq(n, d=timestep)`?

> Parameters:
>   n : int
>   Window length.
>
> d : scalar, optional
>   Sample spacing (inverse of the sampling rate). Defaults to 1.
>
> Returns:
>   f : ndarray
>   Array of length n containing the sample frequencies.

How to determine `n`(window length) and `sample spacing`?

3) Why are transformed values all complex numbers?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm gonna answer in reverse order of your questions

> 3) Why are transformed values all complex numbers?

The output of a Fourier Transform is always complex numbers. To get around this fact, you can either apply the absolute value on the output of the transform, or only plot the real part using:

```
plt.plot(dft_X.real)
```

> 2) To obtain frequency value, should I use np.fft.fftfreq(n, d=timestep)?

No, the "frequency values" will be visible on the output of the FFT.

> 1) Does the graph show the transformed values of the input data? I only used 2 rows of data(each row is a time series), thus data is 2x10000, why are there so many lines in the graph?

Your graph has so many lines because it's making a line for each column of your data set. Apply the FFT on each row separately (or possibly just transpose your dataframe) and then you'll get more actual frequency domain plots.

---

**Follow up**

> Would using absolute value or real part of the output as features for a later model have different effect than using the original output?

Absolute values are easier to work with usually.

*Using real part*
[image: plot of FFT with real()]
*Using absolute value*
[image: plot of FFT using abs()]
Here's the Octave code that generated this:

```matlab
Fs = 4000;                          % Sampling rate of signal
T  = 1/Fs;                          % Period
L  = 4000;                          % Length of signal
t  = (0:L-1)*T;                     % Time axis

freq = 1000;                        % Frequency of our sinousoid

sig   = sin(freq*2*pi*t);           % Fill Time-Domain with 1000 Hz sinusoid
f_sig = fft(sig);                   % Apply FFT

f = Fs*(0:(L/2))/L;                 % Frequency axis

figure
  plot(f,abs(f_sig/L)(1:end/2+1));  %      peak at 1kHz)
figure 
  plot(f,real(f_sig/L)(1:end/2+1)); % main peak at 1kHz)
```

In my example, you can see the absolute value returned no noise at frequencies other than the sinusoid of frequency 1kHz I generated while the real part had a bigger peak at 1kHz but also had much more noise.

As for effects, I don't know what you mean by that.

> is it expected that "frequency values" always be complex numbers

Always? No. The Fourier series represents the frequency coefficients at which the sum of sines and cosines completely equate any continuous periodic function. Sines and cosines can be written in complex forms through Euler's formula. This is the most convenient way to store Fourier coefficients. In truth, the imaginary part of your frequency-domain signal represents the phase of the signal. (i.e if I have 2 sine functions of the same frequency, they can have different complex forms depending on the time shifting). However, most libraries that provide an FFT function will, by default, store FFT coefficients as complex numbers, to facilitate phase and magnitude calculations.

> Is it convention that FFT use each column of dataset when plotting a line

I think it is an issue with mathplotlib.plot, not np.fft.

> Could you please show me how to apply FFT on each row separately

There are many ways to go around this and I don't want to force you down one path, so I will propose the general solution to iterate over each row of your dataframe and apply the FFT on each specific row. Otherwise, in your case, I believe transposing your output *could* also work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do have some further questions following your order:3) Would using absolute value or real part of the output as features for a later model have different effect than using the original output? 2) "frequency values" will be visible on the output of the FFT- based on your explanation to 3), is it expected that "frequency values" always be complex numbers? Could you please explain why it makes sense? 1) Is it convention that `FFT` use each column of dataset when plotting a line? Could you please show me how to apply `FFT` on each row separately? Thank you so much

Comment: @nilsinelabore edited my response to answer your questions

Comment: Awesome answer. Thank you:) If  "frequency values" will be visible on the output of the FFT, what's the difference between `numpy.fft.fft` and `numpy.fft.fftfreq`?

Comment: @nilsinelabore I was wrong, `numpy.fft.fftfreq` will give you the values of the frequency axis for a signal of length `n`. I don't know how you acquired your data but if you know the sampling rate, you can invert it and feed 
it to `numpy.fft.fftfreq` as `d`.

The difference between `fft` and `fftfreq` is that `fft` will give return you the transform of your signal, but to accurately know what frequencies your peaks are at, you need to `fftfreq` to associate your `fft` values with the resulting frequencies.

Comment: Thank you. I have a few questions: 1) May I ask what you mean by the sampling rate? 2) Do I have to know it to use the `numpy.fft.fftfreq` function? So `fft` will only transform the original data, ie. number of input = number of output; whereas `fftfreq`((3) after applying `fft` right?) will return a series of frequency values? 4) How many frequency values are likely to be returned? Thank you so much!

Comment: @nilsinelabore when you're dealing with continuous-time signal, you have to sample it in order to be able to process it. A sound wave, for example, could be sampled at 8kHz for use in a telephone line or 44kHz for a quality music recording. If you don't know the samplig rate, or if there just "isn't" one, fftfreq will default to using 1 as the sampling rate. You don't need to necessarily apply fft and fftfreq in any particular order. They are completely unrelated operations. For a given sampling rate and signal length, fftfreq will always return the same result.

Comment: My original data was forward resampled to create constant time interval for the time series. Or are you referring to another method? Is it wrong if fft defaults to using 1 as the sampling rate in case I don't know the sampling rate? "You don't need to necessarily apply fft and fftfreq in any particular order" -but I do need to apply them together to get the frequency components I want right? Do you mind showing me how to get resample rate from the dataset? I could post another question.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @nilsinelabore if you know the duration of the signal then the sampling rate will be `Fs =(# of samples)/(Duration)`, Since you're looking for `d` anyway you could shortcut to `d = (Duration)/(# of samples)`. You can't know the sample rate if you don't have any information on the duration of the signal. If you don't, I suggest you ask the person you've got the data from.